# Difference between folder size reported by Windows and total file size for Documents and Settings folder

Tags: windows-xp

My Documents and Setting folder occupies 8.42 GB, but When I check the files inside individually it just shows 800 MB. Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost unbelieveable that you 7.6 gb unaccounted for.  I could see being off by a bit due to rounding off or hidden files.

First i would check my math, if correct you could try [WinDirStat](http://windirstat.info/) -it's an awesome little tool that doesn't need to be installed with a very nice GUI that may help you find something you missed.

Also, empty your recycle bin - i don't think that will account for the difference but it might.  In your tags you have temporary files listed -if you believe that may be your problem i can recommend CCleaner.  Would suggest the standard virus/malware scans also.

Answer (score 1):

Can you see all the system and hidden files? These could be taking up some of the space, but 90% seems a bit excessive.

Go to **Tools > Folder Options > View > Advanced Settings**.

You might be able to see more.

You could also install something like [Treesize](http://www.jam-software.com/freeware/index.shtml) which should reveal more information.

Comment: No i have choosed the options to show hidden and system files.

Comment: I'd install TreeSize and use that.